# CS50, PSET4 filter-less: black screen when running blur function

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently working on the blur function, in filter-less, this is an assignment in the CS50 course, on week 4, therefore in problem set 4. I am greeted with a black screen when I run this function,which should blur a bitmap image using the box blur technique. I'm unsure what part of my code is causing this to happen.

Here is my code - any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
// Blur image void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) 
{
    // initialize average variables
    int averageRed = 0;
    int averageBlue = 0;
    int averageGreen = 0;
    float counter = 0;

    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {   
            // create copy of image[i][j]
            copy[i][j]=image[i][j];

            // nest for loops to integrate 9 pixels into algorithm, creates box around pixel
            for (int y = i - 1; y <= i +1; y++)
            {
                for (int x = j - 1; x <= j+1; x++)
                {    
                    // exclude out of bounds pixels
                    if ((y >= 0) &&(y < height) && (x >= 0) && (x < width))
                    { 
                        // find average of middle pixels in contact with each other, round
                        averageRed = copy[y][x].rgbtRed;
                        averageBlue = copy[y][x].rgbtBlue;
                        averageGreen = copy[y][x].rgbtGreen;

                        // ++ sum to average by
                        counter ++;

                        // find average of middle pixels in contact with each other
                        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (int)round(averageRed/counter);
                        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int)round(averageBlue/counter);
                        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int)round(averageGreen/counter);
                    }

                    // reset average values to 0
                    averageRed = 0;
                    averageBlue = 0;
                    averageGreen = 0;
                }
            }

            //copy image[i][j] into copy[i][j] (for loops)
            image[i][j] = copy[i][j];
        }
    }
 
    return;
}
```

Comment: Aside: copy the entire image first.

Comment: Another: you must reset `counter = 0` before you calculate every pixel. The effect of not doing so is that all the averages will be `0` after the first few pixels.

Comment: More: you are not summing the colour values with `averageRed=copy[y][x].rgbtRed;` etc. which should be `averageRed += copy[y][x].rgbtRed;` and the four variable declarations at the top should be moved inside the pixel loop.

Comment: It's terrible practice to initalise the variables twice: before using the first time, and after using them. Initilialise them *once*, just before the point of use.

Comment: @Weather Vane okay, thank you so much for the help. In regards to your first 2 comments,  I am not sure how to copy the entire image first, as I thought I did that at the start with `copy[i][j]=image[i][j]`. And in regards to resetting `counter=0,` would that be straight after I have done `counter++`?

Comment: Copy the image first with its own loops, what's hard? You already copy it but too late (not all the neighbours have been copied). `for(int i=0; i<height; i++) { for(int j=0; j<width; j++) { copy[i][j]=image[i][j]; }}` (and remove from the loops you already have).

Comment: About `counter` no: initialise a variable *before* you use it - it's useless to initialise afterwards. Move those four variable declaration (and initialisation) inside the `j` loop.

Comment: @Weather Vane, sorry I'm still unsure about what you want me to do in regards to copying the image first, and what loops you want me to remove, are you suggesting I remove my i and j loops? and then replace them with what you have written here? As this is the same as what I have in the code here,  Or am I misunderstanding?